# How to use danfo-js with mongoDB and mongoose to build a DataFrame from JSON, windows 10

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am having some difficulty in building a DataFrame using danfo-js with JSON data from mongoDB / mongoose.

For reference I am using danfojs-node: ^0.1.5, mongodb: ^3.3.4 and mongoose: ^5.7.12.

My code is pretty simple and is taken from the danfo-js documentation:

```
const dfd = require("danfojs-node");
import {findTrades} from 'findTrades';

export const makeDataFrame = async () => {   
    try {    
        let data = await findTrades();
        let df = new dfd.DataFrame(data);
        df.head(5).print();    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    };
};
```

This however results in an *undefined*.
For reference my database call is as follows:

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import {dbConnect, dbDisconnect} from './database';
    import {TradeSchema} from '../schemas/TradeSchema';
    const Trade = mongoose.model('Trade', TradeSchema);
    
    
    export const findTrades = async (pairs, exchanges, dateStart, dateEnd) => {
        await dbConnect();
        try {
                const trades = await Trade.find({
                    "pair": {'$in': pairs},
                    "exchange": {'$in': exchanges},
                    "$and": [{'time': {'$gte': dateStart}}, {'time' : {'$lte': dateEnd}}]
                }, {'_id': 0, 
                    'btcValue': 0,
                    '__v': 0})
                    .exec();
                return trades;
        } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        } finally {
        dbDisconnect();
        }  
    };
```

An example console log of the output looks like this:

```
let trades = [
    {
      tradeID: '7955529058',
      price: 53.66,
      quantity: 1.93460576,
      time: '2020-07-28T05:00:00.000Z',
      usdValue: 103.8109450816,
      exchange: 'coinbasepro'
    },
    {
      tradeID: '7955529419',
      price: 53.66,
      quantity: 2,
      time: '2020-07-28T05:00:02.000Z',
      usdValue: 107.32,
      exchange: 'coinbasepro'
    },
    {
      tradeID: '7955529608',
      price: 53.66,
      quantity: 18.61657,
      time: '2020-07-28T05:00:02.000Z',
      usdValue: 998.9651462,
      exchange: 'coinbasepro'
    }
  ]
```

If I input this JSON directly into new dfd.DataFrame(trades) rather than after a database query the DataFrame is produced.  I however, can only get undefined from danfojs-node if I input the data after the database call.  I have looked through the danfo-js documentation and have found no reference to such an issue.  I have attempted to input JSON.stringify(data) and have also input JSON.parse(data.toString()) all to no avail.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK so my solution is to JSON.stringify() the data and then JSON.parse() it:

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Seems kind of ridiculous but works - if anyone knows why this might be please let me know!